# inline attachment opens in new tab with tab title set to url

Tags: grails, attachment

In my app i allow upload and download of attachments, the download controller allows for viewing attachments inline so that a browser with a docs plugin can view the attachment in the browser.

Example of controller response:

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline") 
response.setContentType(mimeType) // example: "application/pdf"
response.outputStream << fileInstance.newInputStream()
```

Example of view link:

```
<g:link controller="document" action="download" id="${doc.id}" title="${doc.title}" target="_blank">${doc.title}</g:link>
```

Problem:
The document is successfully openened in the browser, but the title of that tab is the actual url to the file, e.g: server_url/controller/action/id

Desired:
The tab title should be the file name.

I have searched around, tried a dozen things without any progress so far. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the `filename` parameter? http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266#section-4.3 it should look like this: `response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=whatever.pdf")`

Comment: I did actually before, will double check just in case..

Comment: unfortunately didn't help, the tab title is still the db path. Here is the response header: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-disposition: inline; filename=Groovy_and_Grails_Recipes_2009_-_Apress.pdf
Content-Type: application/pdf
Date: Thu, 15 Oct 2015 12:40:50 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked